# lottie-ios animation completion block getting called immediately

Tags: swift, animation, lottie

I'm using lottie-ios (3.1.6) to implement a sort of loading indicator while an API request is being sent. The animation JSON is the entire beginning-to-ending flow, which I have playing from the beginning, looping the middle section an unknown number of times, and when the API response is received, I'm attempting to seamlessly finish the animation from the point where I currently am.

What's actually happening is: when the API response is received, my completion block is immediately fired without finishing the animation.

```
func showLoading() {
    animationView.play(fromFrame: 0, toFrame: 546) { [weak self]  _ in
        self?.animationView.loopMode = .loop
        self?.animationView.play(fromFrame: 348, toFrame: 546)
}

func dismissLoading(animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
   if animationView.isAnimationPlaying {
        animationView.play(fromFrame: animationView.currentFrame, toFrame: 599, loopMode: .playOnce, completion: { _ in
            UIView.animate(
                withDuration: animated ? 0.3 : 0,
                animations: {
                    self.containerView.alpha = 0.0
                },
                completion: { [weak self] _ in
                    completion?()
                }
            )}
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func showLoading() {
    animationView.play(fromFrame: 0, toFrame: 546) { finished in
        if finished {
            self.animationView.play(fromFrame: 348, toFrame: 540, loopMode: .loop) 
        }
    }
}

func dismissLoading(animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
   animationView.play(fromFrame: animationView.realtimeAnimationFrame, toFrame: 599, loopMode: .playOnce, completion: { _ in
        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: animated ? 0.3 : 0,
            animations: {
                self.containerView.alpha = 0.0
            },
            completion: { [weak self] _ in
                self?.uninstallProcessingViews()
                completion?()
            }
        )
    })
}
```

Figured it out. Be very careful about nested animation completions- playing another segment may send a cancellation up the chain and break it later when you wouldn't expect it to.

Comment: Could you maybe share a more complete code sample? I'm having a similar issue